# display field of json_encode with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request

I want to use ajax to validate a form. So I created this code in Laravel:

```
$nick = Nick::where('slug', $slug)->first();
if($nick){
    $exist =  true;
} else {
    $exist =  false;
}
$a = ['exist' => $exist];
return json_encode($a);
```

And now I want to check that in ajax (I'm using React but it doesn't matter). For the test I try this

```
async value => await fetch("/ajax/my/address").then(async response => console.log(response))
```

How I can check field of exist? This request callback a lot of data - status and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `response.json()` to parse the JSON to an object.

```
async value => {
    const response = await fetch("/ajax/my/address");
    const obj = await response.json();
    console.log(obj.exist);
}
```

BTW, don't mix `await` and `.then()` in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

The resolved value of a `fetch()` call is a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. To get your data, you'll need to extract the response body as JSON using [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json):

```
const yourFunction = async value => {
  const responseObject = await fetch("/ajax/my/address")
  const json = await responseObject.json()

  console.log(json)
}
```